# FirebaseAuth type not found in scope despite successful import in AuthViewModel

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication

I'm currently working on implementing user authentication with Firebase in my iOS app. I've encountered a puzzling issue in my `AuthViewModel` where I'm importing Firebase but still getting errors like:

```swift
Cannot find type 'FirebaseAuth' in scope
```

The perplexing part is that despite these errors, my app builds successfully without any issues when run on the simulator.

Has anyone faced a similar situation, and could you shed some light on why these errors are occurring even when the app builds without any apparent problems during simulation? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I just am on the page and this appears, but disappears once program is ran.

Comment: What is AuthViewModel, and what is its business with Firebase?

Comment: @ElTomato My authViewModel is a class which is responsible for everything authentication related like sign up/log in, setting current user, etc. Here, in order to use firebase methods, i needed to import firebase,  but I get that weird message I was talking about in the post.